# Calling functions without making the script launch

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

The title isnt very accurate i think

Here are my script at the right

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhYly.png)

It's a bot to automatize some actions. Now i want to add some gui to it but i dont know how.

Like you see at the left, i have " import questions" but cuz of it when I launch the tkinter file, it automatically launches the questions without taking my openBtn code into account.

How can I add gui to each command of my questions.py?

Comment: Please add your code in plaintext rather than screenshots.

Comment: Its way way to long, and there is no point tbh, its just to show you at the right side the start of my script, how it calls functions ,and at the left, my start of tkinter try

Comment: Start with tkinter I started yesterday and now i'm implementing plots of matplotlib without problems..

Comment: @Ace If it's too long, create an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: See [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to break your `questions.py` script into actual  ***functions*** .  Python will simply execute all actions in `questions.py` when the namespace is imported before it reaches the logic below the import statements in `testkinter.py`.

So in `questions.py` remove your `while True:` statements in favor of function definitions like:

`def check_database(param):
     database check logic here`

Then link the functions defined in `questions.py` to Tkinter button actions in `testkinter.py` like this:

`w = tkinter.Button( fenetre, command=check_database )`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried what you said but now i have this error :
 >File "testkinter.py", line 6, in <module>
 > w=tkinter.Button(fenetre,command=check_database() )
 > NameError: name 'check_database' is not defined